# Firebase cloud messaging, Unity, Android.. "DllNotFoundException: App" error on Initialise

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

[I have followed this tutorial to setup firebase Cloud Messaging on my Unity client app on Android](http://I%20have%20followed%20this%20tutorial%20to%20setup%20firebase%20Cloud%20Messaging%20on%20my%20Unity%20client%20app)

When I call Firebase for the 1st time here

```
Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.TokenReceived += OnFIRETokenReceived;
```

I get an exception

Here are the logs from logcat (adb logcat -s Unity) when I call the above code

```
03-11 00:50:27.677 28363 28417 I Unity   :
03-11 00:50:35.627 28363 28417 E Unity   : Unable to find App
03-11 00:50:35.687 28363 28417 I Unity   : DllNotFoundException: App
03-11 00:50:35.687 28363 28417 I Unity   :   at (wrapper managed-to-native) Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper:SWIGRegisterExceptionCallbacks_AppUtil (Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGE
xceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExce
ptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExcepti
onHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionH
elper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate)
03-11 00:50:35.687 28363 28417 I Unity   :   at Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE+SWIGExceptionHelper..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
03-11 00:50:35.687 28363 28417 I Unity   : Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for SWIGExcepti
```

I'm on Unity 5.5.1f1.
I've also recently installed sdks for facebook and gameSparks (they are working ok though)

Comment: Try installing Unity patched version, example Unity 5.4.3 p4

Comment: Ye cheers. I would be surprised if firebase only worked on the bleeding edge version of Unity. I am on the 2nd most recent normal build. Changing Unity versions is a bit of a pain. I will try that later when this is completely blocking me. I posted this on Friday so maybe a firebase person will answer it during the week. They say they check SO for firebase tag. Otherwise you can ask them 4 support questions. This will be one of them!